# How Do I Access Class Property From Variable in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created several classes to model JSON data returning from an API. The section with relevance looks like:

```
public class ErrorClass
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string? unknown_properties { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string? invalid_coordinates { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string? location_error { get; set; }
    }
```

Some of these error properties will only show up when an error is present in the JSON to be modeled (null values ignored). I want to setup a helper to handle errors. This will check to see if certain values were populated in the object and add those to error messages respectively. I have a list of property names potentially belonging to an object of a class. I want to loop through the list of strings and check to see if they have a value in the current object. My issue is that I am unsure how to do something like:

```
    public class ErrorsHelper
    {
        string[] badRequestErrors = {"invalid_coordinates", "location_error"};
        public void Process_Errors(dynamic errors)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < badRequestErrors.Length; i++)
            {
                var badRequestError = badRequestErrors[i];
                if (errors.badRequestError[i])
                {
                    // Add to list, etc.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Because the compiler looks for a property of the variable name instead of the value of that variable. How can I look for a property name in a C# object in this fashion?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would use `JObject` instead of deserializing to a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never actually found a solution for this problem. The issue was that `.getType()` only returns the `class type` of the `object` and so running the provided solutions on it would only give the `available` properties and not those that were actually non-null in the object.

Answer (score 1):

Using Reflection, this will return all properties annotated with `JsonPropertyAttribute`.

```
var properties = typeof(ErrorClass)
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>() != null)
                .ToList();
```

You can access their names like this:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
            }
```

You can get their value by:

```
var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
```

Comment: I was trying an approach like this. The issue I ran into is that the class that goes in the `typeof()` can vary. I should have mentioned this. It's used for many different endpoints of which have different error classes.

Comment: Then you should use `.GetType()` or `typeof(T)` if you have a generic method.

Comment: The issue is if I try to use `.GetType()` and then pass that var into the `typeof()` I get an error: `errorType' is a variable but is used like a type`

Comment: `.GetType()` gives you a type. Then you can call `.GetProperties` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The high-level answer is that you would use `reflection`. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Reflection is often discouraged, but it is a valid approach. See:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143205/reflection-is-using-reflection-still-bad-or-slow-what-has-changed-with-ref

For some discussion. A couple of points: it is generally 'slower' (though often not practically), and it can bypass compiler checks (possibly introducing errors).

If any one of your errors is 'bad' enough to stop the whole process, you could also `yield return` in your error checker, and simply check all of the various error types in serial, provided there aren't too many error types.

Answer (score 0):

You can get class properties using below code:

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(ErrorClass).GetProperties();
        
Array.ForEach(propertyInfos, property => 
Console.WriteLine("Property Name is :" + property.Name));
```